# Encountering a problem while using ngrok link for simulations

Tags: simulation, robotics, ngrok, drake, pendulum

I recently started encountering an error with the ngrok link used for simulation. I usually use the function: `meshcat = StartMeshcat()` for simulation the models in deepnote. But recently I started getting a security error sometimes and other times it asks me to sign up and install some authtoken. I signed up for the ngrok account and also installed the authtoken but it still doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Can you let me know how I should set this up so it works? Also, you could recommend some alternative ways (other than ngrok) to do the simulations that would also be really helpful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

We've actually been working with the ngrok folks to see if we can make it easier. https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16300.

But for now I'm afraid you'll need to make a ngrok account and set your token as an environment variable.